# Java - running multiple clients with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, client-server

I've got codes of a server and clients written on Java. But the question is how to run multiple clients on DIFFERENT console-windows with Eclipse when server is running? Thx for helping!
(solved!!)

UPDATE**
Another question: I'll create a new question

Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ATMServer {

    private static int connectionPort = 8989;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    boolean listening = true; 
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(connectionPort); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + connectionPort);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Bank started listening on port: " + connectionPort);
    while (listening)
        new ATMServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

}

ServerThread:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ATMServerThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket = null;
private BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
public ATMServerThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ATMServerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run(){

}
}
}
```

Client: (**UPDATE)

```
import java.io.*;   
import java.net.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATMClient {
private static int connectionPort = 8989;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket ATMSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String adress = "";

    try {
        adress = "127.0.0.1";
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println("Missing argument ip-adress");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        ATMSocket = new Socket(adress, connectionPort); 
        out = new PrintWriter(ATMSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                                (ATMSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown host: " +adress);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't open connection to " + adress);
        System.exit(1);
    }




    out.close();
    in.close();
    ATMSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get a number of consoles for all Java Applications you'll start...

Comment: beny23 is right. Eclipse should do that for you automatically. To see the different consoles, click the console button on the tab that you have it. You should see all your open consoles.

Comment: When I try to open another console to run client, it doesn't run seperate as I wished. When I write something in the first client-console, both the first and second got the output. How to avoid that?

Comment: As the example, when ATM server is running, I want to act two customers to access to the server and do the different things as the server offered. That's why I want to know how to run two clients at the same time. Help? thx

Comment: @Ferry Press the Run button in eclipse twice.

Comment: @nos Done. But both console-windows still doing the same thing... Is there anything I have to change with the code?

Comment: @Ferry Presumably not, but the code for your server is missing. Are you sure your're not just being confused by eclispe automatically (by default) switching to the console that produces output ?

Comment: @nos Thx 4 helping. It's my mistake, I just opened a new console instead of switching between the consoles I've already opened. Problem solved. Thx

Comment: Can you supply the code that's in your run()-method? If the logic in there says that incoming messages should be distributed to all connected clients, then the behaviour you're seeing is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run as many socket clients from Eclipse provided that you pass user-defined ip/port info as command arguments from main() under Program Arguments tab in Run Configuration dialog for that program inside Eclipse rather than using some hardwired values for ip/port.

To create multiple console views (via separate Console View tabs rather than clicking on each instance), you need to create a new console view for each target instance in Eclipse Debug View mode; to achieve this, you need to select "New Console View" (from the icon button with the plus symbol to the far right of the Console View) and assign which program instance to view from each new console.

> Another question: if I have to change something on ServerThread, for example, add a title, is that possible to execute that without restart the server?

Which title? I don't see any GUI code for the ServerThread code snippet. Do you mean the title name of the Console view tab?